# Powershell execute SFTP command

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to make a call to mintty.exe (OpenSSH/SFTP from CygWin) via Powershell.

How can be done most effectively ?

Comment: Just use PuTTY's psftp.exe?

Answer (score 2):

```
Invoke-Expression c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe
```

I made an assumption about the path of your executable.

Also, you should refer to the official documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Comment: Thx.But what if I want to invoke a specific OpenSSH command via CygWin ? I also want to check the result of that call... A little context: I want to invoke from serverA via remote powershell a command on serverB having an OpenSSH SFTP command using CygWin....

Comment: Ok well first of all don't call it "a dos command". It's not DOS. You should take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes

Comment: Or spend a few minutes on google. There is a lot of information about how to do this.

Comment: I called this: invoke-expression 'c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i -e df' to see if I get results from an interactive df statement, but I get no response, only empty string....